# Заполнение ListView только со 2 раза

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Столкнулся с весьма неоднозначной проблемой. Возможно, решение кроется в какой-то маленькой детали, но я никак не могу разобраться. Есть **ФрагментА** с ListView. Есть **БД**, откуда берётся `ArrayList<Class>` и отправляется во **ФрагментеА** адаптеру. При первом переходе на этот **фрагментА**, ListView не выводится. Если вернутся на предыдущий **фрагментБ** и еще раз перейти на **фрагментА**, тогда ListView выводится. В чём может быть проблема? Несколько раз переписывал адаптер, но проблема не решалась.
Вот код фрагмента:

```
public class RegionListFrag extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();


        RegionAddAdapter regionAddAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    RegionNameClass regionNameClass;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).changeTbOn();
        MainActivity.toolbar.setTitle("Регионы");


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.region_layout, container, false);
        MainActivity.toolbar.setTitle("Регионы");
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.region_lv);

        regionAddAdapter  = new RegionAddAdapter(getActivity(),
                setRv());
        listView.setAdapter(regionAddAdapter);
        listView.setPadding(0, 110, 0, 0);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
        Menu myMenu = menu;
        MenuItem nextItem = myMenu.findItem(R.id.accept_category);
        nextItem.setVisible(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.accept_category) {


        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    ArrayList<RegionNameClass>   setRv(){
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(getActivity());
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db.query("regiontable", null, null, null, null, null,
                null);
        ArrayList<RegionNameClass> rvArray = new ArrayList<RegionNameClass>();
        while(c.moveToNext()){
            String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("regNames"));
            RegionNameClass regionObj = new RegionNameClass(name);
            rvArray.add(regionObj);
        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "кол-во массива - " +  rvArray.size());

        return rvArray;

    }
}
```

Код адаптера:

```
public class RegionAddAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RegionNameClass> {

    private static  ArrayList<RegionNameClass> list = new ArrayList<RegionNameClass>();
    private final Activity context;
    public ArrayList<RegionNameClass> selectedStrings = new ArrayList<RegionNameClass>();
    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";
    RegionNameClass regionNameClass;

    public RegionAddAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<RegionNameClass> top) {
        super(context, R.layout.region_row, list);
        this.context = context;
        list = top;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        protected TextView myTv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;

        RegionNameClass myClass = getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.region_row, parent, false);
        }
        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.region_tv);
        tvName.setText(myClass.name);
        return convertView;

    }
}
```

Comment: Нигде в коде не работаете со скрытием и показом вьюшек? Возможно, проблема в этом.
Также логами проверьте, приходят ли вообще данные в адаптер в первый раз

Comment: А метод `getView` это разве не работа с вьюшками? Вроде он как раз и заполняет же адаптер или я что-то не так понял?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй так:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.region_layout, container, false);
    MainActivity.toolbar.setTitle("Регионы");
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.region_lv);

    regionAddAdapter  = new RegionAddAdapter(getActivity(),
            setRv());
    listView.setAdapter(regionAddAdapter);
    listView.setPadding(0, 110, 0, 0);
    regionAddAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // <-----------------------

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: мой ListVIew не распознает метод `notifyDataSetChanged();` , может в этом проблема?

Comment: regionAddAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Да, перепутал, не ту переменную скопировал, извиняюсь, сейчас поправлю. Писал "от руки", а не во андроид студии.

Answer (score 0):

под дебагом setRv() сколько возвращает элементов в первый раз? Попробуйте так курсором пробежать

```
  if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
       do {
           String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("regNames"));
           RegionNameClass regionObj = new RegionNameClass(name);
           rvArray.add(regionObj);
           } while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что и при первом, и при втором разе одинаковое кол-во возвращает..